# How do I wait for the service promise before rendering

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-material

In the view I have:

```
 <md-checkbox ng-disabled={{isGood('test')}}...
```

In the controller I have:

```
$scope.isGood=function(model){
  return  $scope.myData.indexOf(model);
}
```

and:

```
MyService.get({id:1}, function(data) {
  $scope.myData=data;
  .....
});
```

How do I force the rendering of `md-checkbox` to wait until 
`MyService.get` returns with the data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-show, ng-hide, or ng-if to prevent the element from displaying on the page. ng-show and ng-hide will just hide the element. If you want to prevent the element actually being added to the DOM, use ng-if.

So you could do something like:

```
<md-checkbox ng-if="myData" ...>
```

Which will wait until myData is defined to render the element.

Comment: thanks. but the question is how do i prevent isGood expression to be called before MyService.get fulfill his promise

Comment: ng-if will prevent the isGood expression from being called. It will not render it on the page until the ng-if expression is true, and then it will call the isGood expression

Comment: Thanks. I had such a problem and wanted to call an 'ng-init' after a promise was returned. I used 'ng-show' at first on the div and the 'ng-init' function was called at first. I changed it to 'ng-if' and the problem is solved.